# Update the wp title using function or code wihout updating header.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a requirement to update the blog page title with the recent post title. I got the result using this code and its working. I am using get_header() and page title is in header file. I have different templates in theme and blog is also a template page because I am using wp as CMS.

One simple options is copy paste the header code into blog template and apply the title. Is there any other possibility to modify the title using functions or code without copy pasting complete header code into template file.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type'=>'post') );
$queried_post = get_post($query->post->ID);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
_e($title);
```

Comment: Please mark the answers as answered (click the checkmark next to the question). That's how it's done here on stackoverflow. Leave a comment if you have a problem doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can hook into the [`wp_title` callback](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_title) (filter) and change it then. You then do not need to modify each theme's template file. Your callback function then needs to return the new title:

```
function my_title($currentTitle) { # ignoring other settings for now
  $query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type'=>'post') );
  $queried_post = get_post($query->post->ID);
  return $queried_post->post_title;
}

add_filter('wp_title', 'my_title');
```